# How do I add errors to my Spring MVC REST Service?

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

How can I change/update the following REST call from Spring MVC to return a error if the user did not enter of the the two names I was coding for.. something like a *not found*?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public User getName(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model)
{
    logger.debug("I am in the controller and got user name: " + name);

    /*
        Simulate a successful lookup for two users. This
        is where your real lookup code would go.
     */

    if ("name2".equals(name))
    {
        return new User("real name 2", name);
    }

    if ("name1".equals(name))
    {
        return new User("real name 1", name);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to respond with an HTTP 400 error in a Spring MVC @ResponseBody method returning String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-an-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-retur)

Answer (score 10):

Define a new exception class, e.g. `ResourceNotFoundException` and throw an instance of this from your annotated controller method `getName`.

Then also define an annotated exception handler method in your Controller class to handle that exception, and return a 404 Not Found status code, potentially logging it.

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public void handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex)
{
    LOG.warn("user requested a resource which didn't exist", ex);
}
```

Or even returning some error message, using @ResponseBody annotation:

```
@ExceptionHandler(ResourceNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ResponseBody
public String handleResourceNotFoundException(ResourceNotFoundException ex)
{
    return ex.getMessage();
}
```

Comment: but how do I sent it back to the client?? do you have a example of this anywhere

Comment: spring takes care of that for you. read the docs at: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler

Comment: I dont see it on the page.. am I missing something.. how to I tell the client that something is NOT right with the call?

Comment: if I do this then the client will get back a java.lang.NullPointerException.. I want to learn how to pass the error back to the client

Comment: The client of a REST service will be some piece of software -  and as such will be totally happy with a HTTP status 404 and needs nothing more.

Comment: edited answer to show how you can return error message in response body

Answer (score 2):

You could create an object specifically for returning error responses.  That way, you can say whatever you want.  For example:

```
@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> handleHttpMessageNotReadableException(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex){

    ResponseStatus responseStatus = new ResponseStatus("400", "Bad Request. " + ex);
    responseStatus.setResponseStatusTime(timestampService.createTimestamp());
    HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;

    ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> response = new ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus>(responseStatus, status);

    return response;
}
```

In this example you can see that there is a ResponseStatus object.  This object contains a field for a status code, status message, date and time.  You may not need date and time but I find it useful for when someone sends me an error they have seen, because then it is easy to track down exactly where it happened in our server logs.

Comment: `ResponseStatus` is your own class, right?  Because Spring has a `ResponseStatus` annotation.