# Different response from a controller method based on HTTP Response code

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, exception

How do you write a controller method which can either return a View or HTTP response status code based on if its 200 then view else the response status code.

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
 public String showLanding()
 {
    return View.Landing;     
 }
```

I want to handle in case of 401, 403, 500 etc. just status code should be returned instead of view.

Answer (score 0):

To return the 403- Unauthorized status code,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String showLanding()
{
     return HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;    
}
```

**See this:**

1. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html?is-external=true
2. [How to respond with HTTP 400 error in a Spring MVC @ResponseBody method returning String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin)

Comment: You might want to fix your return type.

Answer (score 0):

You could also check out the @ResponseStatus annotation as well as ResponseEntity (for more dynamic scenarios)

Comment: But at a time I can only do one .. right ? As i said i want to have view or response status code

Comment: I am not sure that's such a good idea. Maybe you should separate the controller methods...

Answer (score 0):

I'm far from suggesting that you should do flow control with Exceptions - but those HTTP statuses are errors and exceptions. So you might want to throw business exceptions from your controller methods and then handle those using [@ExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-exceptionhandler)s.

You can also target a subset of Controllers and assist those with Exception handling using [@ControllerAdvice](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice).