# How to return a 400 status code, but return an int

Tags: java, web-services, http-status-code-400

I want to do this instead of a null pointer exception in a java method
`return new ResponseEntity<String>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`
but my method returns an int not a string.
The main thing I want to do is return a 400 Status code. 
What can I do?

I tried `throw new IllegalArgumentException(arg + "is not a valid argument; positive value expected");`
but that returns a 500 status code with a good message.
I'm doing this on a web service if that helps.

I also tried `return new ResponseEntity<Integer>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);`, but that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: What Web-Service Tech do you use? In Jersey I implemented this by deriving my own Exception from WebApplicationException and passed the status code in a constructor. In the web-method you simply throw this custom exception.

Comment: I'm using Jave EE, Spring MVC?

Comment: Duplicate question I guess: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin

Comment: He is returning a String though, I tried Integer, not working :/

Comment: You have to return ResponseEntity<Integer> instead of an int. You have to look at the accepted answer.

Comment: Then provide the error...

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer for this question?