# Spring: responseBody : HTTP status

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am trying to get the list of data as list. But i need to return http status 404 if server is unreachable. for me POST method is working fine , but GET method returns 200 with http.ok to client page. how to add response ?

```
      @RequestMapping(value = "/config/filedata/data", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       @ResponseBody
       public List<filedata> getAllFileDatas()
      {
           return filedataServices.getAllFileDatas();
      }
```

Comment: Could you please let me know what your get method is returning in response??

Comment: Short answer, return the correct type (ResponseEntity).  Read the answer referenced in the fabriziomieli answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this link, it should answer your question.
[How to respond with HTTP 400 error in a Spring MVC @ResponseBody method returning String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin)

In any case, http error code 404 is returned when server is unreachable, so usually it's not a code returned programmatively.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404