# How to POST REST correct error status code using Spring Exception handling

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, spring-mvc

I'm trying to handle missing json data in a POST request. 
My controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/testMetrics")

public class TestMetricsEndPoint extends StatusEndpointHandler implements RestEndPoint<TestMetrics,String> {

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;

@Autowired
private TestMetricsService testMetricsService;

@Override
public Status get(String id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}


@Override
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody Status create(@RequestBody TestMetrics core, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    try {
    if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        throw new InvalidRequestException("Add failed, Please try again ", bindingResult);
    }
    if((core.getGroupName()==""||core.getGroupName()==null)&&(core.getTestName()==null||core.getTestName()=="")){

            throw new MissingParametersException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),"Please provide all necessary parameters");
        } 
    TestMetrics dataObject = testMetricsService.create(core);
    return response(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(),dataObject);
    }catch (MissingParametersException e) {
        return             response(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

Extended class:

```
public class StatusEndpointHandler {


public Status response(Integer statusCode,Object data){
    Status status = new Status();
    status.setData(data);
    status.setStatus(statusCode);



    return status;
}

}
```

Implemented interface:

```
 public interface RestEndPoint<T extends SynRestBaseJSON, ID extends    Serializable> {

Status get(ID id);

Status create(T entity, BindingResult bindingResult);}
```

Result:
[image]

**Please look at the highlighted part**
So, when i tried to test the result through POSTMAN, i'm getting status as 200 OK. I have no idea hot to solve it. please help me with this situation. How to get the correct status code.?

Answer (score 1):

You should change your return type from `@ResponseBody` to [`ResponseEntity`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) which will allow you to manipulate headers, therefor set the status, this is a snippet from the docs

```
 @RequestMapping("/handle")
 public ResponseEntity<String> handle() {
   URI location = ...;
   HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   responseHeaders.setLocation(location);
   responseHeaders.set("MyResponseHeader", "MyValue");
   return new ResponseEntity<String>("Hello World", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear about what you said. I understood that i need to use @ResponseEntity. But, i did not get how to use it.

Comment: I nearly hinted it as a right way to go. You should find plenty of resources to understand why, and how to use it. Basically, its the built-in class that is logic equivalent to your `StatusEndpointHandler`

Answer (score 1):

In your catch statement, try to set the status through

```
response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST  );
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16233227/6592474)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your code handing the string comparison, to compare strings you have to use `equals`, from Postman also you are passing empty testName and groupName

```
    if ((core.getGroupName() == "" || core.getGroupName() == null) && (core.getTestName() == null || core.getTestName() == "")) {
    }
```

so change your code to below

```
    if ((core.getGroupName() == null || core.getGroupName().trim().isEmpty()) && (core.getTestName() == null || core.getTestName().trim().isEmpty())) {

    }
```

also write an `ExceptionHandler` for this

```
@ExceptionHandler({ MissingParametersException.class })
public ModelAndView handleException(ServiceException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    ModelMap model = new ModelMap();
    model.addAttribute("message", ex.getMessage());
    return new ModelAndView("error", model);
}
```

You can also define validation constrains in entity class using validation api, in this case you need to add `@Valid` to the request model object

```
@Entity
class TestMetrics {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    String groupName;

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Column
    String testName;

    // Getters and Setters

}
```

Comment: have you entered `testName` and `groupName` ? it should not be empty or null as per the validation logic

Comment: Yes. I entered bot  of them

Comment: could you post `testName` and `groupName` values inside the method `create`

Comment: updated code with exception handler, have a look at it