# how to change spring default mvc error error code 400 of "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception, http-response-codes

Java Spring MVC

When sending invalid requests (broken JSON for example) to the controller endpoint, the response is:

HTTP status 400: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect"
this is returned without actually entering the controller action.

since my endpoint is open for 3rd parties I want to override this error code (only this kind of error - not all error codes from the endpoint) and modify it.

Overriding the message is optional but would be a nice addition.

** Explain for the duplicate mark: I know how to set the error code once the request lands in the controller action, the issue i am describing is that the request does not enter the action method since the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: You should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin

Comment: you could use a filter

Comment: Please check the Explain section i added. @Aks

Answer (score 0):

I think this kind of error message is MethodArgumentNotValidException.class .
you can use an controller adviser and change returned error code :

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyErrorHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK /*or your optional error code */ )
    @ResponseBody
    public JPresent myHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
  //   handle error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add this code in you web.xml file

```
<error-page>
     <error-code>400</error-code>
     <location>/WEB-INF/views/errorPages/page-error-400.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

you can do the same thing for the rest of error code you want to handle