# binding spring validators with angular 2

Tags: java, spring, angular2-forms

I am using spring boot as back-end and angular 2 as front-end.
My problem consist how to bind spring validators with angular 2.

For example, i implemented crud functionality with spring boot.
i set the attribute `quantite` not empty with annotation `@notEmpty(message="the quantite field should not be empty").`

In the form, if the `quantite` field is empty and when i click on submit button, i want that spring validates the inputs.

**Produit.class**

```
public class Produit implements Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String designation;

private double prix;
@NotEmpty(message="the quantite field should not be empty")
private int quantite;
...
```

**ProduitRestService.class**

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/produits/{id}",method=RequestMethod.PUT) 
public Produit update(@RequestBody @valid  Produit p,@PathVariable Long id)
{
    p.setId(id);  // ??????

    return produitRepository.saveAndFlush(p);
}
```

### **angular 2**

**add.component.html:**

```
<form #addForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(addForm.value)" >

        <div class="md-form">

            <input type="text" id="form4"  class="form-control"  name="des" [(ngModel)]="des" >
            <label for="form4">designation!!!!!</label>


        </div>

         <div class="md-form">

            <input type="number" id="form4"  class="form-control" name="prix" [(ngModel)]="prix" >
            <label for="form4">prix</label>
        </div>

         <div class="md-form">

            <input type="number" id="form4"   class="form-control" #quantiteref="ngModel" name="quantite" [(ngModel)]="quantite" >
            <label for="form4">quantité</label>

            <div [hidden]="quantiteref.valid"  class="alert alert danger"  >  this field must not be empty</div>  // i know this validation in angular 2, but i need the work to be in spring dev
        </div>




        <div class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-deep-purple"  (click)="addProduct()" >ADD</button>
        </div>





       </form>
```

Comment: It appears to be in order, so what doesn't work, exactly?

Comment: how to pass binding from spring to angular 2  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`BindingResult`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/BindingResult.html) object as a parameter of your `update` method.

Thus, you'll be able to check if there is any error like this :

```
public Produit update(@RequestBody @Valid Produit p, BindingResult result, @PathVariable Long id) {
     if (result.hasErrors()) {
         // handle error
     } else {
        // good to go
     }
}
```

Comment: and how to display error in add.component.html ?
this is my main problem

Comment: There are multiple ways. You can modify the method's return type to return JSON containing either the error or the product. Or you can throw an exception and catch it in your Angular code. Or you could also do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin)

Comment: what are types of errors  in  result.hasErrors  bloc  ??

Comment: @AmirChoubani, it will contain all errors found during validation. Read attached class's Javadoc.

Comment: @AmirChoubani `result.getFieldErrors()` will give you the errors related to the form's validation. Reading the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/FieldError.html) will help you.