# Can RequestMapping set default ResponseStatus?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

When I use `@PostMapping`, I will give a `CREATED(201)` response status together by `ResponseStatus` annotation. The same as `@DeleteMapping`, `@PutMapping`, ect.

So, is there any way to set the default response status at different requestMapping?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to respond with HTTP 400 error in a Spring MVC @ResponseBody method returning String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin)

Comment: Sorry, maybe there is something wrong with the description. I know how to return the status code by return ResponseEntity or use ResponseStatus annotation. What I want is whether there is a way to config something, make PostMapping annotation always return 201 without ResponseEntity or ResponseStatus annotation.

Comment: You can try to use `@ControllerAdvice` but I'm not sure if it will solve your problem

Comment: What about using OncePerRequestFilter to set the desired response stuatus?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**You can return `ResponseEntity` from a method of controller as your mapping response**

Example code as follows:

```
@GetMapping("/get")
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> get() {
    return new ResponseEntity<String>("GET Response", HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

You can use same mechanism in `@DeleteMapping`, `@PutMapping` and others.

Comment: Hi, @Zico. Maybe there is something wrong with the description. I know how to return the status code by return ResponseEntity or use ResponseStatus annotation. What I want is whether there is a way to config something, make PostMapping always return 201 without ResponseEntity or ResponseStatus annotation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Or just add annotation @ResponseStatus:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
```

Comment: And put this annotation on the class to make it default for all methods.