# How to handle spring controllers parameter type exceptions

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have simple spring controller.

```
@GetMapping("/test")
@ResponseBody
public String doSomething(@RequestParam int a) {

    return String.valueOf(a);
}
```

when i pass a=1 in query string it works fine.

but when i pass a=abc it gave me this.

```
> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'int'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
> string: "abc".
```

is there a way so i can handle this error and response back to user like a must be numeric.

thanks in advance.

Comment: It's called JSR-303/JSR-349 Bean Validation :  https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@ControllerAdive` to handle such exceptions.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestControllerAdive extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
{
    @ExceptionHandler(value=NumberFormatException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> handleNumberFormatException(NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity({your-error-message}, HttpStatus);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you returning a `View` or `ResponseBody`? This will return a response body, not a view.

Comment: you don't have extend from ResponseEntityExceptionHandler, and ControllerAdvice works only when the exception is thrown within the action method but converters are called before that.

Answer (score 0):

I got Two ways:
1. Using Spring ExceptionHandler

```
@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})
public ModelAndView handleException(Exception exception) {
ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Exception");
modelAndView.addObject("exception", exception.getMessage());
return modelAndView;
}
```

2. Instead of int, use String.

   public String doSomething(@RequestParam String a) {
   // conversion to int; validations & Exception handling logic will come here
   return String.valueOf(a);
   }

we follow in this way. we have a utility class, which will have all conversion and validation logic. each time we just have to call respective method.
like:

```
UtilityClass.isValidInt(a);
UtilityClass.isValidLong(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

The elegant solution for that is catching the Exception and then, use the "ResponseEntity" like this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16250729/2520689

Comment: How will you catch the exception if the problem is a mismatch between the parameter type and the type supplied by the incoming request?