# Seting HTTP Response Code and HTTP Method

Tags: java, spring, http

I have that code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/graph", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public HttpServletResponse graphImport() {

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    GraphJson savedGraph = new GraphJson();

    try {

        Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("graph.json"));

        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;

        GraphJson graph = new GraphJson();
        graph.setSource(jsonObject.toString());
        session.save(graph);

        savedGraph = session.get(GraphJson.class, 1);

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("CREATED");
    return resp;
    //return "id :" + savedGraph.getId() + ", " + savedGraph.getSource();
}
```

And when I use the

> curl http://localhost:8080/graph

When I sent one POST request to that URL I need to return status 201 for created and method POST. Need some help on that. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to respond with HTTP 400 error in a Spring MVC @ResponseBody method returning String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin)

Comment: I need to send both method and status when the function is done.

Comment: "Send method": What do you mean by that?

Comment: I did what that link suggests and got this "There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)". I don't know how to say that, but when I use curl it give me HTTP/a.a 200, i need the 201 which is CREATED and HTTP METHOD POST, but it didnt show that, and by the way, as my code shows on RequestMethod.POST I got an error saying that can't use GET method... i'm really confuse

Comment: When you respond you can return only Http Status Code in which case 201 Created for your POST Request.

Comment: I used @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED) and worked

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
```

between the `@RequestMapping` and `@ResponseCode` and it worked when I sent one post request it returned

> code 201 CREATED

Remembering that the `CREATED` after the `HttpStatus.` could be another code.