# How do I configure validation check in Spring MVC with JSP?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I need a quick help regarding validation check in Spring MVC. I have a basic HTML form *not* the JSTL Tag form. How do I check or implement a straight forward data validation check in Spring MVC? One way in my mind coming right now is to use regex to verify the user name is alphanumeric `[a-zA-Z0-9]`.

But I have seen people use `Validator` do this job. I want to use Validator as it seems more profession.

Second question,

I'm trying to get a Exception handling working properly but it is not working. I want the absolute basic response to happen, `the response throws a HTTP.404` response. My simple method:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/request/view/{id}",method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String requestSubmit(Model model)
```

Now with my response String, how can I do it? After search on Stackoverflow. They said to create a generic class such as `NotFoundException` and extend it `RunTimeException`. But I still don't know how to I set the response intentionally to be 404 or any other response actually, even `Http.BANDWIDTH_EXCEEEDED_RESPONSE`

Comment: Regarding the validation you may give a look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator); regarding to your second question i didn't understand it properly

Comment: Please clarify your use case. What your `requestSublit` method should do? What does `Model` object contain?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata I have the usual method in Spring MVC which return a view as 'String' Everything is fine and normal. But in certain cases, say when the user tries to enter a page not authorized to her, I want to throw a `404` or access denied page. How can I do it? Do I need to create my own set of HTTP failure pages? I don't know how to return it as a view. Its described here, the ResponseEntity is not working for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232833/how-to-respond-with-http-400-error-in-a-spring-mvc-responsebody-method-returnin

Answer (score 1):

Fist thing you should know: it's better to use `POST` instead of `GET` in form submitting. Because when you use `GET`, all your `model` properties sent as url parameter and it's not a good practice.

For using validation, you can use `@Valid` as this:

```
public String requestSubmit(@Valid Model model)
```

Then you can use validation annotation like `@NotNull`, `@Size`, ... at every property of `Model` class you want to validate it.

When a user submits your form, if every form attribute has validation problem, spring throws `MethodArgumentNotValidException` automatically. For getting validation errors, you can use `try-catch` block in your controller or better way is to have central exception handler with `@ControllerAdvice`.